# multiple questions about two-factor analysis of variance

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, variance, heteroscedasticity

I have readings taken at 10 different positions for 3 different treatments ( x 3 reps). The mean for each treatment is different. I am not interested in testing for significant differences in the means, i am interested only in the level of variation.

a) I want to determine if the level of variation in the readings is significantly different depending on the treatment. For this analysis I was going to check for homogeneous of variance using the Bartlett test. Should i take the average of the 3 reps at each position and use the resulting 3 data sets (one for each treatment) as the basis for conducting the Bartlett test or should I run the analysis for each rep and treatment, nine in total.

b) If the difference in the means for the treatments is large can you still use the Bartlett test to check for homogeneity of variances.

c) I also wish to determine if the level of variation at each position (independent of treatment) is significantly different. As I know the means for each treatment is different I assume I can not test for homogeneity of variance by position. Can I use CV% as the basis for this test to help eliminate the effect of the different means?

d) In an ideal world I would like to perform a 2 factor anova (position and treatment) where the response value is variance (or standard dev, CV% etc). If I calculate the variance for each position x treatment based on the 3 reps I no longer have sufficient data to perform an anova.